# jquery page works in ie9 or above but doesnt work in 8 or 7

Tags: php, jquery

[image: normal]
[image: doesnt work]

I can see the ie is default set to 7.
How to prevent this?!

Comment: We need to see your code to offer any help.

Comment: which jquery version are you using?

Comment: Where is the php part of this question?

Comment: If you want to use JQuery on IE 6-8, be sure to include version 1.x as 2.x is does not support it.

Comment: mos, are you serious? How can we even help you with just 2 screenshots of something we have no idea how it was built? Do you believe you'd be able to answer your own question without checking the code?

Comment: Ishan Shah solved my question ! thank you.

Comment: the down vote made me cant post question... please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add meta tag in header like :

```
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

Comment: Move your mouse over the down vote button and a tool tip should appear showing the most common reason for down voting :)

Comment: "X-UA-Compatible header is only supported starting with Internet Explorer 8.", and we are talking about IE 7 here.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Than you very much, you saved my life!

Comment: Hello  Ishan Shah, I face another problem on it. It doesnt work if I put the page into a frame. Please help!